# Uncheck Radiobuttons In GridView With JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, vb.net, gridview

As below code, i can uncheck another rows radiobuttons. **But i need to uncheck only which first column values are same in gridview.**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function SelectSingleRadiobutton(rdbtnid) {
        var rdBtn = document.getElementById(rdbtnid);
        var rdBtnList = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (i = 0; i < rdBtnList.length; i++) {
            if (rdBtnList[i].type == "radio" && rdBtnList[i].id != rdBtn.id)
            {
                rdBtnList[i].checked = false;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

For example in this  [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yj6ho.jpg) when i click the (first row) "**Teklif-2**"

then i want to try uncheck only which first column values are "**5555763648**"

My grid structure is same with [this example](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/12/how-to-make-single-radio-button.html).

Comment: You should use [GroupName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton.groupname(v=vs.110).aspx) property

Comment: İ can't, because sometimes 2 same rows sometimes 3 same rows coming to gridview. I need to read first column value and integrate to if condition in above code.